# Does the Rock Band 3 Midi-Pro Adapter work in Guitar Hero: Warriors of Rock?

Tags: ps3, guitar-hero

Just recently got my MIDI-Pro Adapter, but it doesn't work in GH: Metallica, GH:5, GH: World Tour.  I was thinking of buying GH: Warriors of Rock, but the GH wireless MIDI adapter that came with the Band Hero drums is appalling — it drops notes all the time, whereas the MIDI-Pro in Rock Band 3 seems flawless.

I e-mailed Activision support and they said they didn't know.  So, does it work in Warriors of Rock? I can only guess that the answer is "No", but I would like somebody to verify it either way so I can purchase the game (or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got around to trying this (picked up GH:WoR with the Guitar in a half price sale) and I can confirm it definitely does not work.  The game picks up the MIDI controller only if the switch is set to **D** for drums, but then all attempts to start the game indicate that you're using a standard PS3 controller and the game asks you to plug in a microphone.

With Activision's announcement to drop GH games I don't think we'll see a patch any time soon, either.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried using the midi pro in Guitar Hero: Warriors of Rock for Wii and confirm that it actually does work but the game maps the notes as only the 4 drums plus base pedal, as if it was a RB1/2 drum-kit. No cymbal support.

*Have yet to try older Guitar Hero games on Wii apart from Metallica, which didn't recognise it.*

Now tried it on absolutely all games on wii;
Apart from GH:WoR, GH5 and Band Hero which let it work (presumably as a RB2 kit?), None of the other Guitar hero range will recognise the adaptor as a drumkit (or anything else).

Absolutely ALL Rockband games work with the Midi Pro Wii, Including Lego, track packs, specific band games...And they seem to treat it as either a RB1 or RB2 kit.

I'm very dissapointed at lack of support for metallica (and to a lesser degree the other old GH games), especially as the ps2 version works with a RB1 normal kit...(leading me to think midi-pro outputs as RB2 kit with cymbal support for RB3 pro drums)...so either I dig out the old RB1 kit and my ps2 and never sell them and the ps2 metallica game, or I buy a GH drumkit which I'd hoped I could avoid doing with the midi-pro.

Comment: So it works on some Wii GH games but not the PS3 equivalents.  Still no solution over a year later, what a shame.